# Unable to display SQL database data on Visual basic form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I am facing a problem displaying the records of my table on the visual basic form I have created.

This is my code :

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=HOME-PC\SQLEXPRESS;uid=sa;pwd=123;database=college")

    myconnection.Open()
    mycommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from demo3)", myconnection)
    Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(mycommand)
    Dim mydsStudent As New DataSet()

    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(mydsStudent, "Student")

    ra = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Data Displayed" & ra)

    myconnection.Close()
 End Sub
End Class
```

Note: my database name is "college" , table name is "demo3" . Table contains 2 columns namely name and roll no. How to display the data in those columns on the visual basic form that I have created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call execute non query. You can bind the dataset to a DataGridView. Like this

```
Dim DataGridView1 as new DataGridView()
DataGridView1.DataSource = mydsStudent
'Your table goes here, not sure about the exact propety name, hope it works.
DataGridView1.DisplayMember = "demo3" 
Me.Controls.Add(DataGridView1)
```

Comment: is it DisplayMemeber or DisplayMember ?

Comment: Anuraj : I am getting an error saying DataGridView1 not declared ...how to solve this error ?

Comment: @Parth_90 You need to drag and drop DataGridview in the Form. Or you do like try my answer, I modified it.

Comment: when i drag and drop datagridview on my form ..do i have to include "me.control.add(datagridview1)" line ?

Comment: I m getting error in this line: DataGridView1.DisplayMember = "demo3" ..it says DisplayMember is not a member of DataGridView

Comment: Sorry its DataMember. You can get more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datamember.aspx and if you are dropping the control in the form, no need to add the me.controls.add(...) line.

Comment: @Anuraj : thnx a lot for the help !! :-) ..just one more thing..will the datagridview contain my records in a row-column format ? how will it display the data ?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand the question, it will display the Data in row column format, as normal.